# IMAPv4 Protocol

Tags: email, imap

Can you input some custom header/custom data in imap4 protocol. Thanks.

Comment: What for? You don't send email with IMAP, you only collect it.

Comment: I assume he means in the protocol, not in the mail messages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [IMAP4rev1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3501.txt) is extensible. There are already numerous extensions for this protocol and as long as your server implementation and your clients support a specific extension, there shouldn't be any problem.

You might also want to browse the [Unofficial IMAP Protocol Wiki](http://www.imapwiki.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the protocol wiki; I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify both the server to insert the headers and the client to interpret them. This is probably a bad idea. You probably want to add custom headers to the email messages that are served via imap.